Power of the point
Two circles G1, G₂ intersect at two points M and N. Let AB be the line tangent to these circles at A and B, respectively, so that M is closer to AB than N. Let CD be the line parallel to AB and passing through the point M, with C on G1 D on G2. The lines AC BD meet in E, the lines AN CD meet in P the lines BN and CD meet in Q. Show that EP=EQ Also show that EN is the bisector of CND.
Here is the solution for showing that EP=EQ
Lemma
Given a triangle, ABC and a point P in its interior, assume that the circumcircles of traingle ACP and △ABP are tangent to BC. Prove that ray AP bisects BC.
Proof: Let the intersection of AP and BC be D. By power of a point, BD = AD(PD) and CD² = AD(PD), so BD = CD.
Now, solving the problem:
Let ray NM intersect AB at X. By our lemma, (the two circles are tangent to AB), X bisects AB. Since triangle NAX and NPM are similar, and triangle NBX and traingle NQM are similar implies M bisects PQ.
Now ∠ABM BMD since CD is parallel to AB. But AB is tangent to the circumcircle of ABMD hence ∠ABM = BDM and that implies BMD = ∠BDM.So triangle BMD is isosceles and BM = BD
By simple parallel line rules, EBA = ∠BDM = ∠ABM. Similarly, BAM = EAB, so by ASA criterion,
Triangle ABM and Triangle ABE are congruent.
We know that BE = BM = BD so a circle with diameter ED can be circumscribed around triangle EMD. Join points E and M, EM is perpendicular on PQ, previously we proved MP=MQ, hence triangle EPQ is isoscles and EP = EQ.
I got here, and my mind went kinda blank for proving that EN is the bisector.
This is a modified version of a IMO 2000 problem(just the bisector part). This was proposed to us by our math club teacher.
Image of the situation:


An image says more than a thousand words :-)

Our answer has two parts. In the first part, we prove quadrilateral $ANBE$ is cyclic (see $\mathrm{Fig.\space 1}$). In the second part, we use properties of cyclic quadrilateral $ANBE$ (see $\mathrm{Fig.\space 2}$) to show that $EN$ is the angle bisector of $\angle CND$.
$\underline{\text{Part 1:}}$

We add two auxiliary lines $MA$ and $MB$ to the configuration described in OP’s problem statement. With that we can state that the pair of quadrilaterals $ACNM$ and $BMND$ are cyclic because their respective vertices are located on the circumferences of the circles $G_1$ and $G_2$ respectively. For brevity, let $\measuredangle ACM = \beta$ and $\measuredangle MDB = \alpha$.
The pair of quadrilaterals $ACNM$ and $BMND$ are cyclic because their respective vertices are located on the circumferences of the circles $G_1$ and $G_2$ respectively. Therefore, according to Euclid III.21 (angles of a circle segment), we have,
$$\measuredangle ANM = \measuredangle ACM = \beta\qquad\text{and}\qquad \measuredangle MNB = \measuredangle MDB = \alpha. \tag{1}$$
From (1), it follows that,
$$\measuredangle ANB =  \measuredangle MNB + \measuredangle ANM = \alpha + \beta. \tag{2}$$
Now consider the angles of $\triangle CDE$. We shall write,
$$\measuredangle DEC =\pi-\measuredangle CDE -\measuredangle ECD =\pi–\alpha-\beta. \tag{3}$$
Equations (2) and (3) show that pair of angles $\measuredangle ANB$ and $\measuredangle BEA$ of the quadrilateral $ANBE$ are supplementary. Hence, according to Euclid III.22 (opposite angles of a cyclic quadrilateral), the quadrilateral $ANBE$ is cyclic.
$\underline{\text{Part 2:}}$

Here we add two more auxiliary line segments $O_1A$ and $O_2B$, which are two radii of the circles $G_1$ and $G_2$ respectively.
Since these two radii meet the common tangent $AB$ of the two circles at the tangential points $A$ and $B$ respectively, both of them are perpendicular to $AB$. These two radii are perpendicular to $CD$ as well, because $CD$ is parallel to $AB$. According to Euclid III.3 (radius perpendicular to a chord), $O_1A$ and $O_2B$ intersect and bisect the chords $CM$ and $MD$ at $U$ and $V$ respectively.
Since the perpendicular bisector of the base $CM$ of $\triangle ACB$ passes through its apex $A$, $ACB$ is an isosceles triangle. This leads to,
$$\measuredangle CMA = \measuredangle ACM = \beta. \tag{4}$$
By applying similar arguments to the $\triangle DBM$, we can obtain,
$$\measuredangle BMD = \measuredangle MDB = \alpha. \tag{5}$$
Using (4) and (5), we apply Euclid III.21 to the cyclic quadrilaterals $ACNM$ and $BMND$ to determine the angles $\measuredangle CNA$ and $\measuredangle BND$.
$$\measuredangle CNA = \measuredangle CMA = \beta\qquad\text{and}\qquad \measuredangle BND = \measuredangle BMD = \alpha. \tag{6}$$
Line $CD$ is parallel to the common tangent $AB$ and they are cut by the segments $EC$ and $ED$. Therefore, according to Euclid I.29 (corresponding angles), we have,
$$\measuredangle EAB = \measuredangle ECD = \beta\qquad\text{and}\qquad \measuredangle ABE = \measuredangle CDE = \alpha. \tag{7}$$
Now we turn to the cyclic quadrilateral $ANBE$. Using Euclid III.21 and (7), we state that,
$$\measuredangle ENB = \measuredangle EAB = \beta\qquad\text{and}\qquad \measuredangle ANE = \measuredangle ABE = \alpha. \tag{8}$$
Finally, using the angle-values obtained in (6) and (8), we can express $\measuredangle CNE$ and $\measuredangle END$ in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as shown below.
$$\measuredangle CNE = \measuredangle ANE + \measuredangle CAN = \alpha + \beta $$
$$\measuredangle END = \measuredangle BND + \measuredangle ENB = \alpha + \beta $$
Therefore, $\measuredangle CNE = \measuredangle END$, which proves that $EN$ is the angle bisector of $\measuredangle CND$.

Thank you so much, I cant imagine how much the angle chasing and the solution took

@StanceleMatei  We cannot understand what you mean by $\rm{\text{“I can't imagine how much the angle}}$ $\rm{\text{chasing and the solution took”}}$. Please explain. If you do not agree with our answer, you can tell us so by giving reasons. If you think our answer is correct, you can accept and up-vote it.
